# Make methods available at higher level in a package

Tags: python, package

Consider the following package structure:

```
foo/                          # package name
    spam/                     # module name
        __init__.py
        eggs.py               # contains "bar" method
        exceptions.py         # contains "BarException" class
```

Now in order to call the `bar` method, we have to do

```
import spam
spam.eggs.bar()
```

I'd like to lose `eggs`.

Now I know it is possible to `import ... as` (and `from ... import`), but is there no way to make methods available higher up in a tree?

Things I **do not** want to resort to:

- lots of `from ... import ...`
- putting my `eggs.py` code in `__init__.py` instead
- starred imports
- long names like `spam.exceptions.BarException` (possibly longer)

An example would be to have `exceptions.py` where I define my exception classes.

Whenever I would want to make them available to a user I wouldn't want them to use `spam.exceptions.BarException`, but rather be able to use `spam.BarException`.

Goal:

```
import spam
try:
    spam.bar()   # in this case throws BarException
except spam.BarException:
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "available"?  What exactly do you want to be able to write, in which file, to be able to use what?

Comment: @BrenBarn Added that I'd like to "lose a foo".

Comment: But it looks like you already know the answer to that: do `from foo import foo`, and then you can just do `foo.bar()`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I do not want to oblige a user to use millions of `from` statements,  neither starred imports, nor do I want them to have to write super long exceptions. And I just want a simple `import foo`.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear about what you want.  That is, show example code that you would like to have work, and explain what the goal is.  It now seems that you have stipulations not just about what you want to make available, but how you want users to be able to import stuff, so you need to make those requirements explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__.py`, you can import things from other modules in the package.  If in `__init__.py` you do `from .eggs import bar`, then someone can do `import spam` and access `spam.bar`.  If in `__init__.py` you do `from .exceptions import BarException`, then someone can do `import spam` and then do `spam.BarException`.

However, you should be wary of going too far with this.  Using nesting in packages and modules has a purpose, namely to create separate namespaces.  Explicitly importing a few common things from a submodule to the top level is fine, but if you start trying to implicitly make everything available at the top level, you set yourself up for name collisions down the road (e.g., if one module defines something called `Blah` and then later another module also does so, without realizing they will collide when they're both imported to the top level).

"Forcing" users to use `from` is not an onerous requirement.  If cumbersome imports are required to use your library, that may be a sign that your package/module structure is too cumbersome, and you should combine some things rather than splitting them up into separate directories/files.

Incidentally, the file structure you have indicated in your post has some problems.  The top-level `foo` as you have shown is not a package, since it doesn't have an `__init__.py`.  The second-level `spam` is not a module, since it is not a file.  In your example, `spam` is a package, and it has inside it a module called `eggs` (in the file `eggs.py`); the top-level `foo` directory has no status in the Python packaging system.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great answer. I updated the question, though I guess you understood the issues (and more) already. Rather than keeping it abstract, it really is about the most common functions and the exceptions (which I now also have in my `__init__` but which I would like to separate).

Answer (score 5):

Note that, contrary to your comments, the top `foo` is not the package name, it's just a directory that's (presumably) on your `sys.path` somewhere, and `spam` is not the module name but the package name, and `eggs` is the module name. So:

```
foo/                          # directory package is in
    spam/                     # package name
        __init__.py
        eggs.py               # contains "bar" method
        exceptions.py         # contains "BarException" class
```

---

The key to what you want to do is this:

- Any global names in `spam/__init__.py` are members of the `spam` package. It doesn't matter whether they were actually defined in `__init__.py`, or `import`ed from somewhere else.

So, if you want to make the `spam.eggs.bar` function available as `spam.bar`, all you have to do is add this line to `spam/__init__.py`:

```
from .eggs import bar
```

If you have an `__all__` attribute in `spam/__init__.py` to define the public attributes of `spam`, you will want to add `bar` to that list:

```
__all__ = ['other', 'stuff', 'directly', 'in', 'spam', 'bar']
```

---

If you want to re-export *everything* public from `spam.eggs` as a public part of `spam`, you can just do this:

```
from .eggs import *

__all__ = ['other', 'stuff', directly', 'in', spam'] + eggs.__all__
```

---

And of course you can extend this to more than one child module:

```
from .eggs import *
from .exceptions import *

__all__ = (['other', 'stuff', directly', 'in', spam'] + 
           eggs.__all__ +
           exceptions.__all__)
```

---

This is common in the stdlib, and in popular third-party packages. For a good example, see the source to [`asyncio/__init__.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py) from Python 3.4.

However, it's only really common in this *exact* case: you want your uses to be able to treat your package as if it were a simple, flat module, but it actually has some internal structure (either because the implementation would be too complicated otherwise, or because occasionally users will need that structure). If you're pulling in names from a grandchild, sibling, or parent instead of a child, you're probably abusing the idiom (or at least you should stop and convince yourself that you're not).

Comment: Very nice reference! The explanation is still a bit difficult to grasp at first. (*you will also have to add it there*, and, `__all__ = [ ... ]` is not clear where it is and what there is.

Comment: @PascalvKooten: OK, I'll try to rewrite the explanation to be clearer.

Comment: On your last note. I'd want users to be able to refer to spam.Eggception, while having the exceptions all placed in one file (better for developers I'd suppose?) Would you still think that's abusing the idiom?

Comment: @PascalvKooten: That definitely sounds like a good use. In fact, I'm pretty sure there are examples of that in the stdlib too (except they use the name `error.py` instead of `exceptions.py`—in 2.x, there's a top-level module named `exceptions`, and in earlier versions of 2.x that would make `exceptions.__all__` ambiguous). And that's even one of the few good cases from a sibling import; I think all the separate submodules in `urllib` import from `.error`.