# Python library API with packages

Tags: python, api, package

I developed a python library to write Gerber files, a file format ubiquitous in Printed Circuit Board manufacturing. It is a set of modules with a main module called *gerber_writer* containing the API. A user will typically write

```
from gerber_writer import DataLayer
from gerber_writer import (Circle, RoundedRectangle, Thermal, etc.)
```

where DataLayer is the main class, and Circle etc are ancillary classes to define the pad types (shapes) occurring on your Printed Circuit Boards. So far so good.

To publish it in PyPi I converted this to a package, creatively called *gerber_writer*. The directory structure now is:

```
gerber_writer
|-- __init__.py
|-- gerber_writer.py
|-- padmasters.py
|...
```

A user now writes:

```
from gerber_writer.gerber_writer import DataLayer
from gerber_writer.gerber_writer import (Circle, RoundedRectangle, Thermal, etc.)
```

It does the job but I am not enthusiastic. It looks redundant and it exposes a admittedly small part of the module structure of the package, which it should not do.

I looked at other packages writing formats, and often they get around this by doing the imports in the **init**.py. Something like:

```
from .gerber_writer import DataLayer
from .gerber_writer import (
    Circle, Rectabge, RoundedRectangle, ChamferedRectangle, RegularPolygon, etc, etc.
    )
```

The user now only has to write:

```
import gerber_writer
```

Simple, but I do not really like this either. You now import all pad shapes, also the ones you do not need, but you do not know what you import.  It is equivalent to

```
from something import *
```

with is bad style. I am also told it is best to keep **init** empty.

What is the best way? Is there a better, more pythonic, way?

Comment: It would help to share your file/folder structure. It sounds like this automatic (?) conversion just nested your package inside another folder of the same name, and may be fixed by simply moving everything up one level.

Comment: Thx. I added the file structure.

Comment: I see. You could rename you python file to something shorter and less redundant, or make use of __init__.py (see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429022/make-methods-available-at-higher-level-in-a-package which may get you started but probably doesn't get you all the way without more research)

Comment: The post indeed seems to offer a nice solution to my problem. I will change the name of the module gerber_writer to simpy writer, this is indeed better. Thanks for the help!